# How to detect 2nd appearance of character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am trying to add a toolbox to a MediaWiki Chat using JavaScript. Well, with this code I do a AJAX request to another MediaWiki page (MediaWiki:Chat-herramientas-2) to get the content of the toolbox and, on the chat, print it.

The format of the toolbox content is:

```
- Navigation
 * Page 1
 * Page 2
 * Page 3|Hahaha
 * #|Execute script|hello()
```

The first line is the first < li > of the < ul > (toolbox). It has the class "active".

The second and third lines are "< a >" with href "#", and the text are "Page 1" and "Page 2", respectly.

The fourth line has a href with url ".../Page 3" and the text is "Hahaha".

But with the fifth line, I want to insert a blank href ("#"), with the text "Execute script" and after the 2nd "|" add the onclick attribute with "hello()" on it.

I can't accomplish it because I don't know how to detect the 2nd appearance of a character. The full code is this:

```
$(function() {
    var $chatheader = $('#ChatHeader');

    select = 'MediaWiki:Chat-herramientas-2';

    var $menu = $('<ul class="dropdown"></ul>')
    .insertAfter($chatheader)

    function flatten (options, indent) {
        var flattened = [];
        indent = indent || '';
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            if ($.isArray(options[i])) {
                flattened = flattened.concat(flatten(options[i], '* '));
            } else {
                flattened.push(indent + options[i]);
            }
        }
        return flattened;
    }

    function render (lines) {
        var options = '', selected = ' selected',
            ignore = { '(': 1, ':': 1,  '<': 1 };
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++, selected = '') {
            if (!lines[i].length || ignore[lines[i][0]]) {
                continue;
            }
            var contents = mw.html.escape( lines[i].substring(2) );
            if (lines[i].substring(0, 2) === '* ') {
                var clase = contents.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-').toLowerCase();
                var url = contents.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-').toLowerCase();
                var checksitiene = /\|/g.test(contents)

                if(checksitiene) {
                    var wachem = contents.replace(/\|/,'">');
                    options += '<li class="' + clase + '"' +
                        selected + '><a target="_blank" href="/wiki/' + wachem + '</a></li>';
                } else {
                options += '<li class="' + clase + '"' +
                    selected + '><a href="#">' + contents + '</a></li>';
                }
            } else {
                options += '<li class="active">' + contents + ' <span>▼</span></li>';
            }
        }
        $menu.append(options);
    }

    if (typeof select === 'string') {
        $.get('/wiki/' + select + '?action=raw&ctype=text/javascript')
        .done(function (data) {
            render(data.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/));
        });
    } else if ($.isArray(select)) {
        render(flatten(select));
    }
});
```

Comment: Where in the code do you try and detect the second `|`? It isn't commented and I'm not even clear what you're asking. Is this a regular expression question?

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this:
 * Page 3|Hahaha
but with two | for other attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.indexOf` accepts two arguments, the first is the string you want to match, and the second is the index from which to start your match. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Thus, after using `indexOf` to find the first instance of a string, you can then search from that index+(length of the matching string) to find the next match.

A function that can be called multiple times to receive the next index in a string:

```
function makeIndexer(text,pattern,start){
  start = start||0;
  var patternLength = pattern.length
    , initialStart = start
    ;
  return function(){
    var index = text.indexOf(pattern,start);
    if(index === -1){ //start over from initial start index after we reach the end
      start = initialStart;
    }else{
      start = index + patternLength;
    }
    return index;
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var nextIndex = makeIndexer("Wow, what an awesome function!","w")
nextIndex() //2 still case sensitive like indexOf
nextIndex() //5
nextIndex() //14
nextIndex() //-1 Like indexOf, returns -1 when there are no more matches
nextIndex() //2 starting over
```

Comment: Can you provide inputs and outputs for your code? So list the data and precisely how you want to manipulate it with your code.

Comment: Input:
- Navigation
 * Page 1
 * Page 2
 * Page 3|Hahaha
 * #|Execute script|hello()

Output:
<ul>
<li class="active">Navigation</li>
<li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Page_3">Hahaha</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="hello()">Execute script</a></li>
</ul>